# Unable to use CrudRepository with Spring Data JPA - "cannot be referenced from a static context"

Tags: java, spring, controller, spring-data-jpa

I am working on a project where I have to use Spring Data JPA to access my database.
For that, I followed this tutorial: https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-mysql/

I adapted the example given in my project but unfortunately, i get a "cannot be referenced from a static context".

My Entity:

```
import javax.persistence.Entity;


@Entity
public class JobList {
    private int total, page, limit;

    public int getTotal() {
        return total;
    }

    public void setTotal(int total){
        this.total = total;
    }

    public int getPage() {
        return page;
    }

   public void setPage(int page){
        this.page = page;
   }

   public int getLimit() {
        return limit;
   }

   public void setLimit(int limit){
        this.limit = limit;
   }

}
```

My Repository:

```
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;

public interface JobListRepository extends CrudRepository<JobList, Integer> {

}
```

My Controller:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(path="/demo") 
public class HomeController {

    @Autowired
    private JobListRepository jobListRepository;

    @GetMapping(path="/add")
    public @ResponseBody String addNewJobs () {
        JobList jobList = new JobList();
        jobList.setLimit(50);
        JobListRepository.save(jobList);
        return "Saved";
    }

    @GetMapping(path="/all")
    public @ResponseBody Iterable<JobList> getAllJobs() {
        return JobListRepository.findAll();
    }

}
```

And when I try to compile:

> HomeController.java: non-static method save(S) cannot be referenced
>   from a static context HomeController.java: non-static method findAll()
>   cannot be referenced from a static context

I can't really understand this error since addNewJobs() and getAllJobs() are not static.

Thanks.

Comment: `JobListRepository` should be `jobListRepository` case sensitive.

Comment: Holy... you are right. I can't believe i lost hours on this. Thank you!

Comment: *facepalm* same issue here, thanks a bunch!